# JSON result format with JS

Tags: javascript, json

I have an input form like this:

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <label class="text-info">name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" />
 </div>
```

and a basic script like below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#postform").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = {
                name: $("#name").val().trim(),
                requestID: $("#requestID").val().trim(),
                label: $("#label").val().trim(),
                contractTypeID: $("#contractTypeID").val().trim(),
                contractID: $("#contractID").val().trim(),                
            }
            console.log('{"ABC":' + JSON.stringify(data) + '}')
               ....

        })
    })
```

The results JSON with following:

```
{
    "name": "Demo",
    "REQID": "1234aa",
    "label": "123",
    "contractTypeID": "321",
    "contractID": "1234",
}
```

But, I need result to be formatted like this:

```
{
   "ABC":{
      "name":"Demo",
      "REQID":"1234aa",
      "Group":{
         "label":"123",
         "contractTypeID":"321",
         "contractID":"1234"
      }
   }
}
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this or I will need to hardcode result?

Comment: Where exactly is the key `"ABC"` coming from in your example? Why do you need it?

Comment: Well, how do you know that the property name should be "ABC"? What about what fields go into the "Group"?

Comment: Create the object you want, `var x = { "ABC": data }` then do stringify on that. `JSON.stringify(x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the arbitrary key `"ABC"` as per your example, you can just wrap your `data` structure into that pre-defined parent object:

```js
var data = {
  "name": "Demo",
  "REQID": "1234aa",
  "label": "123",
  "contractTypeID": "321",
  "contractID": "1234",
};

var modifiedData = {

  "ABC": {
    "name": data.name,
    "REQID": data.REQID,
    "Group": {
      "label": data.label,
      "contractTypeID": data.contractTypeID,
      "contractID": data.contractID
    }
  }

};

console.log(modifiedData);
```

Comment: Thank for your help. And how about "Group"?

Comment: @Alex Missed that the first time around, in which case you can just manually map the keys to the values

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var data = { 
  ABC: {
    name: $("#name").val().trim(),
    REQID: $("#requestID").val().trim(),
    Group: {
      label: $("#label").val().trim(),
      contractTypeID: $("#contractTypeID").val().trim(),
      contractID: $("#contractID").val().trim(),                
    }
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this.  Another way is to build up your javascript object in stages like this:

```
var data = { ABC: { Group: {}}};
data.ABC.name = 'Demo';
data.ABC.REQID = '1234aa';
data.ABC.Group.label = '123';
data.ABC.Group.contractTypeID = '321';
data.ABC.Group.contractID = '1234';

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Just remember that javascript objects do not support **order** like javascript arrays do, so it won't **look** exactly how you specified it but this does produce the object you specified.

Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anandamasri/hwrs7n1v/11/).